# hard refresh/ reload when pages are loaded using ajax #

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a mobile application and am struggling to get my head around the whole loading pages via ajax and am struggling to get pages to reload / refresh data.

For example, if I have a list of products on one page all with URLs looking like `#/product/123232` to ensure the page is loaded using ajax. I select a product to take me to the product page, this page is loaded by ajax.  On the product page I can delete the product or update the product details.  If the product is deleted I try to use `window.location.href = redirect;`  to take me to the previous page which lists the products.  However, the product I have deleted is still there due to the page still loading via ajax.  I need to refresh the page for this to load update product list. How can I get this to do this automatically?

Another example is messages are marked as read / unread but when browsing from page to page the messages are not updating whether they are read or unread uness I refresh / relaod the page using f5.  How can I get it to do it automatically using jquery?

Comment: Confused!!!!... Can you the show the issue and explain on the basis of that?

Comment: confused as well. There's not enough information. I don't understand what are you using (normal jquery or jquery-mobile? mobile app or mobile website? there are differences...)

Comment: When product is deleted, can you set flag so that product list is reloaded (if flag is set) when you navigate to list?

Comment: I am using Kendo Mobile UI.  I understand Ajax and have used it in many applications but usually to make changes on a page so the page does not need to reload.  When navigating away from that page, normally the pages are reloaded and content is always fresh so if I go back to that page the content is reloaded and up to date.  My problem is with this UI is when I am navigating from page to page, the content is not reloaded from the server as the content of the pages has been pulled in via ajax and is not updated.  Hope that is clearer...:0(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of the whole async part. When you submit some via ajax you should either receive the updated html or someting as answer which you will insert into the dom, or you will receive an ok and do update it yourself, like removing an entry from a list.

Comment: If I select a product info page and select delete, I get OK back so I then want to redirect the user to the product listing page but the product listing page still shows the entry I have just deleted.  I just want that page to refresh.

Comment: How to you to the redirect? If you just fire a browser back event then this may be the reason. These ajax hash navigations normally work with the browser history. There are still the old values stored. There should be a way to force an async reload of the data.

Comment: I have been using window.location.href = redirectURL; but the page does not refresh with this.  I just need to know how to force the page to reload as that exactly my problem the ajax hash navigations are storing old values.